# Webpack Angular2 with ng2-bootstrap: System is not defined

Tags: angular, webpack

I'm using Webpack Angular2 ([See here](https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter)) and I want to include ng2-bootstrap ([See here](http://valor-software.com/ng2-bootstrap/#/)).

ng2-bootstrap depends on SystemJS, but I don't know how to include that correctly.

This is my package.json:

```
{
"name": "my-app",
"version": "1.0.0",
"description": "",
"keywords": [""],
"author": "",
"homepage": "",
"license": "MIT",
"scripts": {
"build:dev": "webpack --config config/webpack.dev.js --progress --profile --display-error-details",
"build:docker": "npm run build:prod && docker build -t angular2-webpack-start:latest .",
"build:prod": "webpack --config config/webpack.prod.js  --progress --profile --bail",
"build": "npm run build:dev",
"ci": "npm run lint && npm test && npm run e2e",
"clean:dist": "npm run rimraf -- dist",
"clean:install": "npm set progress=false && npm install",
"clean:start": "npm start",
"clean": "npm cache clean && npm run rimraf -- node_modules doc coverage dist",
"docker": "docker",
"docs": "npm run typedoc -- --options typedoc.json --exclude '**/*.spec.ts' ./src/",
"e2e:live": "npm run e2e -- --elementExplorer",
"e2e": "npm run protractor",
"github-deploy:dev": "webpack --config config/webpack.github-deploy.js --progress --profile --github-dev",
"github-deploy:prod": "webpack --config config/webpack.github-deploy.js --progress --profile --github-prod",
"github-deploy": "npm run github-deploy:dev",
"lint": "npm run tslint \"src/**/*.ts\"",
"postversion": "git push && git push --tags",
"prebuild:dev": "npm run clean:dist",
"prebuild:prod": "npm run clean:dist",
"preclean:install": "npm run clean",
"preclean:start": "npm run clean",
"pree2e": "npm run webdriver:update -- --standalone",
"preversion": "npm test",
"protractor": "protractor",
"rimraf": "rimraf",
"server:dev:hmr": "npm run server:dev -- --inline --hot",
"server:dev": "webpack-dev-server --config config/webpack.dev.js --progress --profile --watch --content-base src/",
"server:prod": "http-server dist --cors",
"server": "npm run server:dev",
"start:hmr": "npm run server:dev:hmr",
"start": "npm run server:dev",
"test": "karma start",
"tslint": "tslint",
"typedoc": "typedoc",
"version": "npm run build",
"watch:dev:hmr": "npm run watch:dev -- --hot",
"watch:dev": "npm run build:dev -- --watch",
"watch:prod": "npm run build:prod -- --watch",
"watch:test": "npm run test -- --auto-watch --no-single-run",
"watch": "npm run watch:dev",
"webdriver-manager": "webdriver-manager",
"webdriver:start": "npm run webdriver-manager start",
"webdriver:update": "npm run webdriver-manager update",
"webpack-dev-server": "webpack-dev-server",
"webpack": "webpack"
},
"dependencies": {
"@angular/common": "2.0.0",
"@angular/compiler": "2.0.0",
"@angular/core": "2.0.0",
"@angular/forms": "^2.0.0",
"@angular/http": "2.0.0",
"@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0",
"@angular/platform-server": "2.0.0",
"@angular/router": "3.0.0",
"@angularclass/conventions-loader": "^1.0.2",
"@angularclass/hmr": "~1.2.0",
"@angularclass/hmr-loader": "~3.0.2",
"@angularclass/request-idle-callback": "^1.0.7",
"@angularclass/webpack-toolkit": "^1.3.3",
"admin-lte": "^2.3.6",
"assets-webpack-plugin": "^3.4.0",
"bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
"core-js": "^2.4.1",
"http-server": "^0.9.0",
"ie-shim": "^0.1.0",
"jquery": "^3.1.1",
"ng2-bootstrap": "^1.1.5",
"ng2-bs3-modal": "^0.10.4",
"rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
"systemjs": "^0.19.38",
"zone.js": "~0.6.17"
},
"devDependencies": {
"@types/core-js": "^0.9.34",
"@types/hammerjs": "^2.0.33",
"@types/jasmine": "^2.2.34",
"@types/node": "^6.0.38",
"@types/protractor": "^1.5.20",
"@types/selenium-webdriver": "2.44.29",
"@types/source-map": "^0.1.27",
"@types/uglify-js": "^2.0.27",
"@types/webpack": "^1.12.34",
"angular2-template-loader": "^0.5.0",
"awesome-typescript-loader": "^2.2.1",
"codelyzer": "~0.0.28",
"copy-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.1",
"css-loader": "^0.25.0",
"exports-loader": "^0.6.3",
"expose-loader": "^0.7.1",
"file-loader": "^0.9.0",
"gh-pages": "^0.11.0",
"html-webpack-plugin": "^2.21.0",
"imports-loader": "^0.6.5",
"istanbul-instrumenter-loader": "^0.2.0",
"json-loader": "^0.5.4",
"karma": "^1.2.0",
"karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0 ",
"karma-coverage": "^1.1.1",
"karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
"karma-mocha-reporter": "^2.0.0",
"karma-phantomjs-launcher": "^1.0.2",
"karma-remap-coverage": "^0.1.1",
"karma-sourcemap-loader": "^0.3.7",
"karma-webpack": "1.8.0",
"parse5": "^1.3.2",
"phantomjs": "^2.1.7",
"protractor": "^3.2.2",
"raw-loader": "0.5.1",
"rimraf": "^2.5.2",
"source-map-loader": "^0.1.5",
"string-replace-loader": "1.0.5",
"style-loader": "^0.13.1",
"to-string-loader": "^1.1.4",
"ts-helpers": "1.1.1",
"ts-node": "^1.3.0",
"tslint": "3.15.1",
"tslint-loader": "^2.1.3",
"typedoc": "^0.4.5",
"typescript": "2.0.3",
"url-loader": "^0.5.7",
"webpack": "2.1.0-beta.22",
"webpack-dev-middleware": "^1.6.1",
"webpack-dev-server": "^2.1.0-beta.2",
"webpack-md5-hash": "^0.0.5",
"webpack-merge": "^0.14.1"
},
"repository": {
"type": "git",
"url": ""
},
"bugs": {
"url": ""
},
"engines": {
"node": ">= 4.2.1",
"npm": ">= 3"
}
}
```

This is my vendor.browser.ts:

```
// Angular 2
import '@angular/platform-browser';
import '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import '@angular/core';
import '@angular/common';
import '@angular/forms';
import '@angular/http';
import '@angular/router';

// AngularClass
import '@angularclass/hmr';

// RxJS
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/mergeMap';

import 'jquery';
import 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap';
import 'admin-lte/dist/js/app';
import 'ng2-bootstrap/bundles/ng2-bootstrap'

if ('production' === ENV) {
  // Production
} else {
 // Development
}
```

However, I get this error in runtime:

[image]

When I add `import 'systemjs/dist/system';` in vendor.browser.ts I get a compile error:

```
ERROR in ./~/systemjs/dist/system.js                                                                                                 
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'c:\Projects\Fandango\front\node_modules\systemjs\dist'                               
@ ./~/systemjs/dist/system.js 4:18271-18284
@ ./src/vendor.browser.ts                                                                                                           
@ multi vendor
```

I'm really new to webpack, but I think I'm on the right track?

Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should remove "import 'ng2-bootstrap/bundles/ng2-bootstrap" from vendor.browser.ts because webpack will look import statments in your app.module.ts or main.ts and import what components are needed for your project and not import entire ng2-bootstrap library like here when you add 
"import 'ng2-bootstrap/bundles/ng2-bootstrap'" in your vendor.browser.ts file.

[Look here for using ng2-bootstrap with webpack:](https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-bootstrap#with-webpack-angularclassangular2-webpack-starter)